# FlaskApp - Setup VS Code Debugger after install flask-socketio extension

Tags: python, flask, vscode-debugger, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I'm running a flask rest api using vscode as the IDE. I could setup the VSCode launcher in order to debug the application.

## launch.json

```
  {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "wsgi.py",
            "FLASK_ENV": "development",
            "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--host",
            "0.0.0.0",
            "--port",
            "5000",
        ],
        "jinja": false,
        "justMyCode": true
    },
```

I need to use web sockets, so I've installed flask_socketio and eventlet extensions. To make the app working again I've replaced

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

by

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=True, log_output=True)
```

After that, the VS Debugger stopped working.

Do any of you know if it is possible to configure VSCode to continue debugging this app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To use the VSCode debugger with eventlet or gevent you have to enable the `gevent` option, as indicated in [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_gevent).

The option is named after gevent, but should have been named "greenlet" really, as I have found that it also applies to eventlet.